# How do I get the graphical bootsplash on my Macbook Air?

Tags: boot, plymouth

After upgrading to 12.04, the Plymouth bootsplash screen isn't present. Instead I get a text based version. How can I get the higher-resolution graphical Plymouth bootsplash back?

Comment: What does your `/etc/default/grub` file say?  There should be a line that starts `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`.  What is the entire line?

Comment: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=pci acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Comment: It looks like you've modified your Grub config.  Could you post all of it?  Also, are you using the proprietary nvidia driver?

Comment: http://hpaste.org/67855 - yeah I'm using the proprietary nvidia driver.

Comment: Hi Luke.  I took a look and see nothing amiss (unfortunately).  The usual problem with the Nvidia prop driver is that the Plymouth splash is the wrong/low resolution, but in your case, it can't even boot in a lower resolution, which is odd.  Anyway, the usual way of fixing the former is to uncomment `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` and set it to the appropriate resolution.  So that might work for you too.

Comment: Close voters:  This question has a useful (and probably correct) answer.  **This should not be closed.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Chan-Ho Suh](https://askubuntu.com/users/43660/chan-ho-suh) answered this in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118735/how-do-i-get-the-graphical-bootsplash-on-my-macbook-air#comment153747_118735):

> Hi Luke. I took a look and see nothing amiss (unfortunately). The
>   usual problem with the Nvidia prop driver is that the Plymouth splash
>   is the wrong/low resolution, but in your case, it can't even boot in a
>   lower resolution, which is odd. Anyway, the usual way of fixing the
>   former is to uncomment `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` and set it to the
>   appropriate resolution. So that might work for you too.

To uncomment a line in a configuration file like `/etc/default/grub`--which is the file to be modified in this situation--remove the `#` at the beginning.

After modifying `/etc/default/grub`, the command `sudo update-grub` must be run, to apply the changes.